# Why InetAddress.getByName().isReachable() works on device but not on the Eclipse AVD?

Tags: android, networking, ping, android-virtual-device, connection

I test if device is up in the network with simple piece of code:

```
ip_addr="172.16.1.24";
isAvailable = InetAddress.getByName(ip_addr).isReachable(2000);
```

That code will always return return false on my Eclipse AVD even despite the ip_addr is connectable and the subsequent request to it with http will succeed.

On the other hand if the app is installed on the accual android tablet it will work as expected and the isAvailable will true reflect the fact if the ip_addr is reachable.

This make the debug very dificult as I cant rely on the Emulator any more.

Comment: Are you sure that your address is accessible for the emulator? Can you explain what is this address mean? Is it in wifi network and how do you check that it is accessible?

Comment: I'm 100% positive the device is accesibble from the emulator. This is a server/router that I query for some statistics over http, I then create a graph from the data. And the part of the software that comunicates with the device over http is WORKING fine both in the emulator and in the and in the tablet. So the server/router is connectable in the AVD as I get valid data from it over TCP/IP.  The problem is with the above code, that behaves diffrently in the emulator AVD and the tablet itself. In the tablet it will show true status of the device. In the AVD isAvailable always returns false.